# Removing unwanted users from assignee list

Tags: jira

I have a fairly vanilla JIRA cloud instance with 5 developers, however when assigning an issue, using the box to search for a user, I see what appears to be spam users in my list.

How do I remove these users? They do not show in the /admin/users section, as active or inactive users.

[image: Screenshot of assignees]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point to check is within the [project permissions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/managing-project-permissions-802592442.html) (Toolgear->Projects->select project->Permissions). Since your users appears in the Assignee dropdown on the issue page, the user must be a member of the "Assignable User" permission.

As you will be see from the project permission page (which is really just displaying permissions from the underlying permission scheme), the Assignable User permission is potentially composed of specific groups of users, project roles, or a few other options. You'll need to follow the trail of options selected there to figure out where the users are coming from.

For example, if the permissions include project roles, you can see those from another tab in the project section (the tab will be either "Roles" or "Users and roles", depending on your JIRA version).

If that permission instead includes some specific hardcoded groups from the user directory, you would need to edit the permission scheme directly to remove or change it. (Be aware that the permission scheme could be used by multiple projects, so you'd also need to make sure that your changes did not impact those projects, or else duplicate the permission scheme so that you have a unique copy for your own project.)

A useful blog post providing a high-level overview of JIRA permissions is [here](http://blog.tempo.io/2015/jira-best-practices-jira-permissions/).

As for why you cannot find the phantom users in the User Manager: this is puzzling, but if you confirm that the Assignable Users permission was incorrectly scoped and you fix it, maybe this question will become moot.

I have never personally seen a case where users in the Assignee dialog could not be found in the user directory, but perhaps there is some sort of caching issue. In this scenario, I recommend [re-syncing your presumed LDAP directory connection](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/synchronizing-data-from-external-directories-802592362.html) to make sure it is up-to-date, and then checking to see if the problem recurs once the sync is complete.

Comment: Just to reiterate, he has a **Cloud** instance which means the directory is delegated to Atlassian's own server, he can't sync or do anything like that.

Comment: Sorry--I missed the cloud part. But tracing the permissions as described in the first part of the answer will still hopefully yield some results. Out of curiosity, is this instance also using JIRA Service Desk?

Comment: Yes, we do have JIRA service desk enabled, though it is not currently being used.

Assignable User is currently set to: Application access (Any logged in user)

Comment: I've found that I can get to the user's page by going to https://instancename.atlassian.net/admin/users/view?username=email@domain.com

In here I can see that the application access is all unticked, and the user has "restricted portal access" and shows as "PORTAL ONLY"
I can't seem to find a way to browse to this user via a list, but I am able to delete the users in this manner.

Comment: Best practice is to configure the Assignable User permission in the permission scheme to use a project role (say, the "Developer" role), and then at the project level, just add the five or so individual users who are expected to be assignees (or add a user group containing those users, if such exists) to the Developer role in your project. That should cure your assignee problem. (This should moot the other issue, but while we're still there: could the PORTAL ONLY people possibly be remnants of people who previously accessed your Service Desk?)

Comment: They seem to be bots that have registered for the service desk. I'll set up a "developer" role, and that should resolve the issues, thank you for your help!